# jquery mobile popup with iframe

Tags: jquery, iframe, mobile, popup

jquery mobile1.2
I use following code to popup with iframe,but click the outside page,the popupdiv cannot close(not click the close button on the topright)

why?

html:

```
    <a href="javascript:popup()" data-role="button">pop</a>

    <div data-role="popup" id="popDiv" class="ui-content">
    <a href="#" data-rel="back" data-role="button" data-theme="a" data-icon="delete" 
    data-iconpos="notext" class="ui-btn-right">Close</a>
    <iframe id="dynaitcFrame" seamless></iframe>
    </div>
```

js:

```
        function popup(){
        $("#dynaitcFrame").attr("src","aaa.html");
        $("#dynaitcFrame").attr("height","500");
        $("#dynaitcFrame").attr("width","500");
        $("#popDiv").popup("open",{transition:'pop',positionTo:'#popPosition'});
        }
```